# Determining Internet Backbones from ASN

Tags: internet

I am new to this layer of networking so I apologize if this question is a bit strange.

When running a traceroute, I get the up addresses of the route it takes.  Now, I take these addresses and map the ASN number.

My question (and again being very new), how can I determine the internet backbones.  Basically I want to determine programmatically if a backbone is active and responding.  Perhaps I am asking the wrong question I know

Comment: Can you expand on how you "Now, I take these addresses and map the ASN number" ? Do you have your own AS? Is this to work out if your peer AS routes are up?

Comment: Anything you can't get from http://www.internetpulse.com/ ?

Comment: I have my IP addresses from my traceroute and I run it through a geoip service.  I guess, in the end, I am trying to figure out the whole concept of ASNs.  Basically, I want to map out and get a backbone from one of my sites to my location via the backbones.  Is a lower ASN number indicative of a backbone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Fixed Orbit search page](http://www.fixedorbit.com/search.htm), enter the ASN, and it will tell you what ASNs are directly connected to it.  Unfortunately, that does not understand parent/child relationships, so you see all neighbors, from small multi-homed companies, to huge "backbone" ISPs.  If there are few connections, like most places have, you can often eyeball it and say "Level-3, QWest, Cogent, and AboveNet are their uplinks, and MIT and UMass are their customers".

To get some more ideas of them in a hierarchical view, you can "telnet route-views.routeviews.org" and run "show ip bgp IP_ADDRESS" for an IP within their range, or "show ip regex AS" to see paths that have that AS in it.